# Long loadtimes with MyFontsWebfontsKit.css

Tags: html, css, import, fonts, webfonts

Has anyone used MyFonts.com to use webfonts?
I bought one to use on a new site and the css file they ask me to include seems to add massive wait times on pageload.

```
/* @import must be at top of file, otherwise CSS will not work */
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/*");


@font-face {font-family: 'Trenda-Black';src: 
url('webfonts/*.eot');src: url('webfonts/*.eot?#iefix') 
format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/*.woff2') 
format('woff2'),url('webfonts/*.woff') 
format('woff'),url('webfonts/*.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

That is the css file they tell me to attach to my html's *head*, which I did here:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">
</head>
```

I'm having to wait 16 seconds for the page to load where it normally takes less than one (site is on my hard drive only atm). The fonts do work though.

Does anyone know a solution?
I heard @import is not good to use, is that why? The css comment instructs me not to remove it.